# Django filter for not null

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I have a filter defined as such:

```py
class MessageFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):
    seen = filters.BooleanFilter(field_name="seen_at", lookup_expr="isnull")
```

And it sort of works. But it's the wrong way around, passing seen=True will return all the unseen messages.

I don't want to have to change the name of the url parameter, how do I invert the lookup expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class MessageFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):
    seen = filters.BooleanFilter(field_name="seen_at", lookup_expr="isnull", exclude = True)
```

From [Django Filter Reference Docs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#exclude):

> **exclude**
>
> A boolean that specifies whether the Filter should use filter
> or exclude on the queryset. Defaults to False.